# Empty result when reading in from web table using selenium and python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

[inspect source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qv3rm.png)

```
string = [ ]

bot = myBotManifesto('USERNAME','PASSWORD')

truck_num = bot.driver_web_browser.find_element_by_css_selector
('tr#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PopupControlTractores_TractorGrid_DXDataRow0>td:nth-child(6)')

string.append(truck_num.text)

print(string)
```

THE RESULT IS an empty list. Im not sure why.
That is my main problem .
Once i have that down , id like to read in the same css_selector but for the next tr in the web table.

any help or tips would be greatly appreciated.

---

[ ' ' ]

Comment: Such identifiers are a sign of page generation. Are you sure the id is always the same?

Comment: @cauf , im very new to selenium and python. thats probably the issue. Your saying the id = 'tr#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PopupControlTractores_TractorGrid_DXDataRow0>td:nth-child(6)' probably is regenerated each time so its different ?.  Id need to find a way to get a selector or xpath that doesnt change so i can fix this? If im correct do you have any links or something i can look at so i can do research on this . thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*easier way to do this that works. however i believe in my case the information is protected. Im going to ask for advice on a different question. But this code works for me .*

```
def click_single_tractor(self): #dynamically clicks tractor
    sleep(2)
    basecss = '#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PopupControlTractores_TractorGrid_DXMainTable > tbody > tr'
    cssbase = '#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PopupControlTractores_TractorGrid_DXHeadersRow > td'

    table_rows = self.driver_web_browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(basecss)
    table_data = self.driver_web_browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(cssbase)

    for index, tr in enumerate(table_rows,1):
        iteratingSelObj = self.driver_web_browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("{}:nth-child({})".format( basecss, str(index)))
        print('table row:',int(index))

        for indx, td in enumerate(table_data,1):
            iterate_td = self.driver_web_browser.find_element_by_css_selector("{}:nth-child({})".format( cssbase, str(indx)))
            print('table data:',int(indx))
            if indx == 6:
                #get value of element
                # add to string ? to get value
                self.mystr.append(td.text)

    print(self.mystr)
```

result:

**table row: 1**

table data: 1

table data: 2

table data: 3

table data: 4

table data: 5

table data: 6

table data: 7

table data: 8

table data: 9

table data: 10

**table row: 2**

table data: 1

table data: 2

table data: 3

table data: 4

table data: 5

table data: 6

table data: 7

table data: 8

table data: 9

table data: 10

**table row: 3**

table data: 1

table data: 2

table data: 3

table data: 4

table data: 5

table data: 6

table data: 7

table data: 8

table data: 9

table data: 10

**table row: 4**

(all the way up to 7 rows because thats how many there was and 10 table datas each row )

['Num. Económico', 'Num. Económico', 'Num. Económico', 'Num. Económico', 'Num. Económico', 'Num. Económico', 'Num. Económico']

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the locator, that is not a stable one.
You will need to define it in another way to make it unique and to don't depend on front-end code which can change each time you refresh the page or the table loads new data.
If you can share your html code, we can try to help you with the locator.

Comment: very new to selenium and python. Any link i can so i can do research on this would be very helpful . I know selenium has a method for when xpath changes slightly . May this be a route or do you suggest something else? Thanks for the answer above and any other advise is appreciated.